# How to implement a "conditional foreign key" restriction?

Tags: sql

I have the following table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    A SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    B SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    C SOMETYPE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (A,B),
    FOREIGN KEY (A) REFERENCES Y (A)
);
```

I want to add the following constraint: If `C IS NOT NULL`, then `FOREIGN KEY (A,C) REFERENCES X (A,B)`. How do I do that (without using a trigger, if possible)?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, but this should be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: So there are scenarios where C will be null but A won't?

Comment: Yes. A is a part of the primary key, and I am not a fan of nullable primary keys. WRT C, C will be null most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get what you want you need to have a primary key on A in table Y and a unique constraint on A,B in table Y.

Try this:

```
create table Y
(
  A int not null,
  B int not null,
  primary key (A)
);

create unique index IX_Y_AB on Y(A, B);

create table X 
(
    A int not null,
    B int not null,
    C int null,
    primary key (A, B),
    foreign key (A) references Y(A),
    foreign key (A, C) references Y(A, B)
);
```

Test:

```
insert into Y values (1, 2)

insert into X values (1, 1, null) -- OK
insert into X values (1, 2, 2)    -- OK
insert into X values (1, 3, 3)    -- Fail
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're overthinking things:

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    A SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    B SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    C SOMETYPE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (A,B),
    FOREIGN KEY (A) REFERENCES Y (A),
    FOREIGN KEY (A,C) REFERENCES X(A,B)
);
```

If a referencing column (e.g. `C`) is null, then the foreign key will not be checked. So, if `C` is null, the second foreign key isn't checked. But if `C` is not null, then `A,C` has to match an `A,B` combination in this same table.